# NavigationUI.setupActionBarWithNavController causes the app to crash on startup after Android kills the app in the background

Tags: android, kotlin, navigation, crash

In my activity onCreate method I use the following way to set my actionBar to show and handle taps on the up button:

```
val navController = this.findNavController(R.id.exerciseNavHostFragment)
NavigationUI.setupActionBarWithNavController(this, navController)
```

The issue happens when I send my app to the background and it gets killed by the OS, and when I start the app it crashes. Trying to start the app once again, it runs with no problem the crash only occurs on the first app start after the kill.

The app crashes on the NavigationUI.setupActionBarWithNavController line with the following crash log (Inspecting the navController before the crash shows the graph is null):

```
06-08 15:02:55.262 10162  6624  6624 E AndroidRuntime: FATAL EXCEPTION: main
06-08 15:02:55.262 10162  6624  6624 E AndroidRuntime: Process: com.rawcode.calisthenicsmastery, PID: 6624
06-08 15:02:55.262 10162  6624  6624 E AndroidRuntime: java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to start activity ComponentInfo{com.rawcode.calisthenicsmastery/com.rawcode.calisthenicsmastery.exercises.ExercisesActivity}: java.lang.IllegalStateException: You must call setGraph() before calling getGraph()
06-08 15:02:55.262 10162  6624  6624 E AndroidRuntime:  at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:3160)
06-08 15:02:55.262 10162  6624  6624 E AndroidRuntime:  at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:3303)
06-08 15:02:55.262 10162  6624  6624 E AndroidRuntime:  at android.app.servertransaction.LaunchActivityItem.execute(LaunchActivityItem.java:78)
06-08 15:02:55.262 10162  6624  6624 E AndroidRuntime:  at android.app.servertransaction.TransactionExecutor.executeCallbacks(TransactionExecutor.java:108)
06-08 15:02:55.262 10162  6624  6624 E AndroidRuntime:  at android.app.servertransaction.TransactionExecutor.execute(TransactionExecutor.java:68)
06-08 15:02:55.262 10162  6624  6624 E AndroidRuntime:  at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1991)
06-08 15:02:55.262 10162  6624  6624 E AndroidRuntime:  at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:106)
06-08 15:02:55.262 10162  6624  6624 E AndroidRuntime:  at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:216)
06-08 15:02:55.262 10162  6624  6624 E AndroidRuntime:  at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:7258)
06-08 15:02:55.262 10162  6624  6624 E AndroidRuntime:  at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method)
06-08 15:02:55.262 10162  6624  6624 E AndroidRuntime:  at com.android.internal.os.RuntimeInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(RuntimeInit.java:494)
06-08 15:02:55.262 10162  6624  6624 E AndroidRuntime:  at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:975)
06-08 15:02:55.262 10162  6624  6624 E AndroidRuntime: Caused by: java.lang.IllegalStateException: You must call setGraph() before calling getGraph()
06-08 15:02:55.262 10162  6624  6624 E AndroidRuntime:  at androidx.navigation.NavController.getGraph(NavController.java:677)
06-08 15:02:55.262 10162  6624  6624 E AndroidRuntime:  at androidx.navigation.ui.NavigationUI.setupActionBarWithNavController(NavigationUI.java:168)
06-08 15:02:55.262 10162  6624  6624 E AndroidRuntime:  at com.rawcode.calisthenicsmastery.exercises.ExercisesActivity.onCreate(ExercisesActivity.kt:30)
06-08 15:02:55.262 10162  6624  6624 E AndroidRuntime:  at android.app.Activity.performCreate(Activity.java:7353)
06-08 15:02:55.262 10162  6624  6624 E AndroidRuntime:  at android.app.Activity.performCreate(Activity.java:7344)
06-08 15:02:55.262 10162  6624  6624 E AndroidRuntime:  at android.app.Instrumentation.callActivityOnCreate(Instrumentation.java:1275)
06-08 15:02:55.262 10162  6624  6624 E AndroidRuntime:  at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:3140)
06-08 15:02:55.262 10162  6624  6624 E AndroidRuntime:  ... 11 more
```

I didn't find any similar questions on SO, and I'm new to Android development, any help on what I may be doing wrong is appreciated.

I use the latest dependencies for navigation:

```
// Navigation
    implementation "android.arch.navigation:navigation-fragment-ktx:2.3.0"
    implementation "android.arch.navigation:navigation-ui-ktx:2.3.0"
```

The app has a bottom navigation bar that switches between activities, each activity having their own navHostFragment.
Here is my main activity layout xml:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent">
    
    <fragment
        android:id="@+id/exerciseNavHostFragment"
        android:name="androidx.navigation.fragment.NavHostFragment"
        android:layout_width="0dp"
        android:layout_height="0dp"
        android:navigationBarColor="@color/navigationBarColor"
        app:layout_constraintBottom_toTopOf="@+id/navigation"
        app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintVertical_bias="1.0"
        app:defaultNavHost="true"
        app:navGraph="@navigation/exercise_navigation" />

    <include
        android:id="@+id/navigation"
        layout="@layout/item_bottom_navigation"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_gravity="bottom"
        app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent" />

</androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout>
```

Comment: Are you using `app:navGraph` in your layout XML where you declare your `NavHostFragment`? It would be helpful if you could include your activity's layout XML.

Comment: @ianhanniballake yes, added the xml, and a short description of the navigation architecture of the app, if you think any more info is needed to find the issue let me know.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You're using the wrong dependencies. When you use

```
implementation "android.arch.navigation:navigation-fragment-ktx:2.3.0"
implementation "android.arch.navigation:navigation-ui-ktx:2.3.0"
```

You aren't actually using Navigation 2.3.0, but the last version of `android.arch.navigation` - Navigation 1.0.0.

You need to update your dependencies to match those on the [Navigation Declaring dependencies documentation](https://developer.android.com/jetpack/androidx/releases/navigation#declaring_dependencies) and use `androidx.navigation`:

```
implementation "androidx.navigation:navigation-fragment-ktx:2.3.0"
implementation "androidx.navigation:navigation-ui-ktx:2.3.0"
```